# Laravel ->get() returning null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a collection in Laravel 5.3 that I created after a query, this `dd()` is just one item, didn't want to spam to much...

```
Collection {#950
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => Callrail {#942
      #table: "callrails"
      #appends: []
      #with: []
      #hidden: []
      #casts: []
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:2 [
        "hourofday" => 1
        "calls" => 2
      ]
      #original: array:2 [
        "hourofday" => 1
        "calls" => 2
      ]
      #relations: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #forceDeleting: false
      -originalData: []
      -updatedData: []
      -updating: false
      -dontKeep: []
      -doKeep: []
      #dirtyData: []
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT #1:

Here is the `$calls->toJSON()` output:

```
[
    {
        "hourofday":1,
        "calls":2
    },
    {
        "hourofday":15,
        "calls":1
    },
    {
        "hourofday":16,
        "calls":4
    },
    {
        "hourofday":18,
        "calls":7
    },
    {
        "hourofday":19,
        "calls":2
    },
    {
        "hourofday":20,
        "calls":1
    },
    {
        "hourofday":22,
        "calls":2
    }
]
```

The problem is, when I try to do:

```
    $i = 0;
    while($i != 24) {
        $response[]  = array(
            'name' => date('g A', strtotime('2016-01-01 '.$i.':00:00')), 
            'y' => $calls->whereStrict('hourofday', $i)->get('calls', 0);
        );
        $i++;
    }
```

Every value in the `$response` always has `0`, or `null` if I don't put a default value in.  The values exist, they are in the collection, and are properly formatted, but for whatever reason I can't get them. Is there something I am missing?

Current Documentation:

https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-get

EDIT #2:

Found the answer with help from @Andrej Ludinovskov and the correct answer:

```
$i = 0;
while($i != 24) {
    // You have to get the first item in the array, then you can use it like normal
    $callCount = $calls->whereStrict('hourofday', $i)->first(); 
    $response[]  = array(
        'name' => date('g A', strtotime('2016-01-01 '.$i.':00:00')),
        'y' => ($callCount?$callCount->calls:0)
    );
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have collection of elements and it has keys start from 0 to n. The key 'calls' is a key of an item of this collection. So your code should look like:

```
$i = 0;
while($i != 24) {
    $item = $calls->whereStrict('hourofday', $i)->get(0, null);
    $cnt = 0;
    if ($item != null) {
        $cnt = $item->calls
    }
    $response[]  = array(
            'name' => date('g A', strtotime('2016-01-01 '.$i.':00:00')), 
            'y' => $cnt
        );
    $i++;
```

}

Comment: That results in a `Call to a member function where() on integer` error, which makes even less sense...

Comment: And also, when I tried `dd($calls->whereStrict('hourofday', $i))`, it gives me that collection that is in the original question. Do I have to do `->first()` before `->get()`?

Comment: Vars overlapped each other. Check the current code.

Comment: I guess you can use only first without get.